# nose2 config file behavior

Tags: python, nose2

Hoping someone can clarify nose2 config behavior. I am wondering if this config file behavior is expected or not. I have a project like this:

- dir

  - tests

    - scenarios

      - default.py

        - another_cfg.cfg
        - unittest.cfg

A couple questions:
I am in the tests directory. How come if I do:

```
$ tests> nose2 -c sdfsdf.cfg scenarios.default
```

I don't get any error about not finding the config file specified?

Also, how come if in the tests directory and I do this:

```
$ tests> nose2 -c ./another_cfg.cfg scenarios.default
```

nose2 doesn't read from the config file, but if I go up a level and do:

$ dir> nose2 -c tests/another_cfg.cfg tests.scenarios.default

nose2 DOES read from the named config file?